# Anyone know of any good tutorials for Accessibility Testing Framework?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, accessibility

I am trying to find a tool that can help a developer in eclipse keep up to date with correct markup respecting accessibility.

The tool I have come across is this one:

http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project_summary.php?projectid=technology.actf

I have managed to test out web pages from within eclipse, but I can't seem to get the GUI Accessibility feature to work on a JFrame.  Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe there's any way to test Swing based applications with this tool. If you look at
http://www.eclipse.org/actf/docs/users/aDesigner/docs/overviewGui.html
The tool appears to test API's such as MSAA and IAccessible2. JFrame is part of the Swing toolkit so does not support any of these interfaces. In order to make Swing applications accessible you need the [Java Access Bridge](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136191.html) and a supported screen reader. [NVDA](http://www.nvda-project.org) is an open source screen reader that supports the Java Access bridge. To my knolidge there is no way to do automated accessibility testing of Swing applications. If you need to make a Swing application accessible you'll have to manually test it out with a screen reader. Also of note is the fact that the Java Access bridge is not widely supported and has not been updated in several years and will not run in a 64 bit JVM. A new version of the access bridge is in beta and will work with 64 bit JVM's but most likely will require updated screen reader support. I do not know of any screen readers that officially support the new beta. More info about the beta can be found at
http://jdk6.java.net/6uNea.html